# How to read the token from header response in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, http-headers, token

My team has developed a REST service using spring boot. The task is to build a login module. Authorization is done in back end. The token is provided in back end to the "Authorization" field of the token.

Now I want to read this token from angular 2.

What I have is:

```
  authenticateUser(user: ILogin): Observable<Response> {

    const url = `${this.baseUrl2}`

  //  console.log("the username after service is " + user.username + " and the password is " + user.password)

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log("the json format is " +JSON.stringify(user));

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user))
                    .map((response: Response) => {

                        let userJson = response.headers;

                        console.log("the token is" +userJson.token); // here I got a type error and the error is that there is no token as the field of headers. 


        })
                   .do(data => console.log('authenticateuser:' + JSON.stringify(data)))
                   .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

I am trying to search on Google and I did not find any way how to read the token from the headers.Can anyone help me?

P.S: I can read the token if I modify my code from

```
let userJson = response.headers;
```

to

```
let userJson = response.json().token
```

but the problem is that in back end the token is placed on the header and if I change my code as above it means that I am looking for token to the body and I got a Runtime error if I compile the code.

Comment: so... what is the problem if you can read the headers and thus the token?

Answer (score 0):

```
authenticateUser(user: ILogin): Observable<Response> {    
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log("the json format is " +JSON.stringify(user));

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user))
                   .do((data:response) => {console.log(data.headers.get('token'))}))
                   .map((response: Response) => <any> response.json())
                   .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain a bit about your code.